# search the particular field value in inner sub document of sub document to Mongo db using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Mongodb collection containing a number of documents with the following structure

`{

   "_id": ObjectId("52f4a5ed07b0f7106a9d5e4c"),

   "FM_ID":"1253",

   "passwd": ".aDoSkljf_h+6589q76w3rJK",

   "Area": {

     "0": {

       "X": "53543500",

       "Y": "14031500",

       "images": {

         "0": {

           "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1a84"),

           "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 

        },

         "1": {

           "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1a87"),

           "ImageType": NumberInt(2) 

        }

      } 

    },

     "1": {

       "X": "53543500",

       "Y": "14094572",

       "images": {

         "0": {

           "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aa8"),

           "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 

        },

         "1": {

           "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aab"),

           "ImageType": NumberInt(2) 

        },

         "2": {

           "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aae"),

           "ImageType": NumberInt(0) 

        }

      } 

    },

     "2": {

       "X": "53480464",

       "Y": "14031500",

       "images": {

         "0": {

           "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1acc"),

           "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 

        }

      } 

    }`

want to filter the ImageType=2  collection only

`andQueryObj.add(new BasicDBObject("Area", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("images", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("ImageType", "2"))))));`

This query is not work. how to filter the inner object element value based data..?

Answer (score 0):

1) One issue I see is that you typed:

`BasicDBObject("imageType", "2")`

I think it should be:

`BasicDBObject("ImageType", "2")`

i.e. `ImageType` should be capitalized.

2) Also try this.

`BasicDBObject("ImageType", new Integer("2"))`

I mean, your ImageType is NumberInt in MongoDB, so you should
try Integer in Java. Currently you are looking for the String "2", and
not for the Integer 2.